# RE2 expression to extract string up to the sequence " :" if present

Tags: google-sheets, re2

I'm using the google sheets function REGEXEXTRACT() to search a string and return that string back with everything from " :" and after removed, if that string is present.

Example inputs:

Sydney Distr Center
Port Macquarie
Port Macquarie : Port Macquarie Display
Taree
Taree : Taree Display

Desired output:

Sydney Distr Center
Port Macquarie
Port Macquarie
Taree
Taree

The closest I got so far was using this expression:

^[^\s:]+

However, many of the inputs contain spaces that I want to keep, and this ended up returning:

Sydney
Port
Port
Taree
Taree

I need it to return all the text before it encounters \s: in sequence, and also if it doesn't. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of following formulas:

**REGEXEXTRACT**

```cpp
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1&" :","(.+?) :")
```

**REGEXREPLACE**

```cpp
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(.+) :.+","$1")
```

Or without regex:

```cpp
=INDEX(SPLIT(A1," :",),1)
```

Comment: Just tried this, but it only works if the string " :" is present. All other entries return the error:

Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 2 value "(.*) :" does not match text of Function REGEXEXTRACT parameter 1 value "Sydney Distr Center".

Comment: did you try the solution in the edited answer?

Comment: I just tried both of the solutions from your edit and it's nearly there but not quite. The output for "Taree : Taree Display" is "Taree " when I want it to be "Taree". Is the problem that the delimiter argument in SPLIT() seems to want a character not a string?

Comment: Thank you! I just came back here to say that the key was setting the third argument in SPLIT() to 0. I'll try the regex version too just to figure out how it works but my problem is solved, cheers

Comment: yeah! but setting the argument to 0 is not sufficient, I also had to change the delimiter from `:` to ` :`